# three.js rotate object on mouse down and move

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to get a good mouse movement in my scene so I can rotate around the object.

I have two problems, I can figure out how to limit the movement so that it never rotates below 0 degrees on the Y axis. (I dont want to see the object from below, only above)

And the second thing I can't figure out is how to make the movement smooth. Now with what I have achieved in the jsfiddle is that the camera moves back to its starting position before starting to rotate.

My try: http://jsfiddle.net/phacer/FHD8W/4/

This is the part I dont get:

```
var spdy =  (HEIGHT_S / 2 - mouseY) / 100;
var spdx =  (WIDTH / 2 - mouseX) / 100;

root.rotation.x += -(spdy/10);
root.rotation.y += -(spdx/10);
```

What I want without using an extra library: http://www.mrdoob.com/projects/voxels/#A/afeYl

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can rotate your scene with this code.

To ensure to not rotate under 0, simulate rotation of a vector (0,0,1) and check if y of vector is negative.

```js
var mouseDown = false,
    mouseX = 0,
    mouseY = 0;

function onMouseMove(evt) {
    if (!mouseDown) {
        return;
    }

    evt.preventDefault();

    var deltaX = evt.clientX - mouseX;
    var deltaY = evt.clientY - mouseY;
    mouseX = evt.clientX;
    mouseY = evt.clientY;
    rotateScene(deltaX, deltaY);
}

function onMouseDown(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    mouseDown = true;
    mouseX = evt.clientX;
    mouseY = evt.clientY;
}

function onMouseUp(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    mouseDown = false;
}

function addMouseHandler(canvas) {
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
        onMouseMove(e);
    }, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
        onMouseDown(e);
    }, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function (e) {
        onMouseUp(e);
    }, false);
}

function rotateScene(deltaX, deltaY) {
    root.rotation.y += deltaX / 100;
    root.rotation.x += deltaY / 100;
}
```

Comment: Dont you need just: canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove, false); ?? BTW i like your solution

Comment: Is it still working with latest ThreeJS? `addMouseHandler(document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0]);` doesnt work for me...

Comment: @ProblemFactory : yes, ensure you have a root object in your scene.

Comment: Six years on, it's still a great answer.