# Three JS: How to rotate object instead of rotating the camera?

Tags: javascript, three.js

In Three JS, is it possible to rotate the object with mouse instead of rotating the camera with OrbitControls.js (https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/controls/OrbitControls) Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19589151/4045502)

Comment: thanks @prisoner849

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19588602/three-js-rotate-object-on-mouse-down-and-move/19589151#19589151

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can listen to 'mousemove' event and apply an increment to the objects rotation.

This is a very easy working solution to start with:

```
var canvas = renderer.domElement;
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);

function onMouseMove(event) {
  cube.rotation.y += event.movementX * 0.005;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/go2fhr3v/14/

Answer (score 11):

I solved this problem this way:

I created the 'ObjectControls' module for ThreeJS that allows you to rotate a single OBJECT (or a Group), and not the SCENE.

Include the libary:

Usage:

var controls = new ObjectControls(camera, renderer.domElement, yourMesh);

You can find here a live demo here: https://albertopiras.github.io/threeJS-object-controls/

Here is the repo: https://github.com/albertopiras/threeJS-object-controls.

Comment: Can it keep mouse momentum ?